# get all RadioGroup options ID

Tags: java, android

> Why is it possible to change the background color but it's not to set
>   the new text????

```
RadioGroup allRadioGroups[] = {button1, button2};
```

> why I can do these ones:

```
allRadioGroups[0].getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#216059"));

allRadioGroups[1].getChildAt(3).setEnables(false);
```

> but I can't do these ones:

```
allRadioGroups[0].getChildAt(1).isChecked();

allRadioGroups[1].getChildAt(3).setText("My Text");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I can't do these ones:

```
allRadioGroups[0].getChildAt(1).isChecked();
allRadioGroups[1].getChildAt(3).setText("My Text");
```

Because `getChildAt` method return `View` object.`isChecked` and `setText` methods are not from `View` class.these methods  *from class(RadioButton) which extends View class*

So, to get these lines work cast return `View` to `RadioButton` :

```
((RadioButton)allRadioGroups[0].getChildAt(1)).isChecked();
((RadioButton)allRadioGroups[1].getChildAt(3)).setText("My Text");
```